# Alternative to Google visualisation API

Tags: javascript, api, open-source, visualization

Is there a good (and free) alternative to Google's visualization API?
Something to provides support for drawing 3D charts using js and/or SVG , that also doesn't require installing new plugins on the clients browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://raphaeljs.com is a very nice library